# Can someone clarify the use of the width of the ellipsoid regarding Mahalanobis distance?

Tags: statistics, machine-learning, mahalanobis-distance

My knowledge of Math is limited. I was looking up Mahalanobis distance out of curiosity, after seeing a reference.

From Wikipedia: Mahalanobis distance - Intuitive explanation

Putting this on a mathematical basis, the ellipsoid that best represents the set's probability distribution can be estimated by building the covariance matrix of the samples. The Mahalanobis distance is the distance of the test point from the center of mass divided by the width of the ellipsoid in the direction of the test point.

Maybe naively, I don't understand the use of width. Why not radius instead, and what would be the difference? I didn't see why radius would be symmetric along the width, unless the shape is a perfect ellipsoid and also if the center of mass coincides with the center of the ellipsoid.

Have I misunderstood?

Specifically, as this may apply to ML and classification, I don't see why it has to be a perfect ellipsoid. I was wondering if the accuracy could be improved.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in your intuition, but you have to understand the ambiguity in the statement in Wikipedia's page (which perhaps should be addressed?). The covariance matrix only determines the shape (relative sizes / eccentricities) of the ellipsoid, and not its actual size (in that sense, one could argue that the Wikipedia statement is actually incorrect).

Your intuition comes from thinking of that ellipsoid as having a radius equal to the standard deviation for the given axis; I can only conjecture that the intuition of the person who wrote that statement in Wikipedia comes from the [Gaussian multivariate distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution), which shows the Mahalanobis distance divided by 2 in the exponent; that probably made them think of the ellipsoid's size being divided by 2, thus having half the standard deviation as radius.

As for your other comment: it doesn't *have to* be a perfect ellipsoid; it just *is*. The equation $D_\mathrm{M}(\mathbf{X},Q) = C$ (where $D_\mathrm{M}$ denotes Mahalanobis distance between $\mathbf{X}$ and distribution $Q$ and $C$ is a positive constant) is the equation of an ellipsoid (including the possibility of a hypersphere). So, for M.L. applications, whenever the Mahalanobis distance applies (either explicitly or implicitly), then an ellipsoid is indeed the right tool to visualize it (notice that the ellipsoid is virtually never *explicitly used* in any calculations)